# AES 128 CBC mode Help

Tags: arduino-uno

Firstly i printed input[16] then encrypted it and printed the cipher and finally decrypted and printed input[16] but why my result is not matching after decryption ???????

I tried with different baud rate and also different input output array but not working.

Library Used: https://rweather.github.io/arduinolibs/classCBC.html

```
#include <CBC.h>
#include<AES.h>
CBC<AES128> cbc;

 void setup() {
 // put your setup code here, to run once:
 Serial.begin(9600);

 uint8_t key[16] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15}; 
 uint8_t iv[16] = {0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3};
uint8_t input[16] = {0,1,2,3,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3};
size_t len = 16;

cbc.setKey(key, 16);
cbc.setIV(iv, 16);

for(int i=0; i<16; i++)
Serial.print(input[i]);
Serial.println("");

cbc.encrypt(input, input, len);
delay(1000);

Serial.print("input:");
for(int i=0; i<16; i++)
Serial.print(input[i]);
Serial.println("");

cbc.decrypt(input, input, len);
delay(1000);

Serial.print("input:");
for(int i=0; i<16; i++)
Serial.print(input[i]);
Serial.println("");

cbc.clear();
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Create a separate output array. Currently the output variable is the same as the input. Depending on the algorithm this can be problematic.